# More link not displaying in content pane

Tags: 7, views

I've got a Content Pane View which I display multiple times on one page (it shows a grid of Employees and takes a Department as a parameter, so I show the View 4 times on a page, sending each one a different Department parameter).

Each view on this page shows only a subset of the results (it only shows 6 Employees from each Department). I want to add a More link at the bottom of each view that links to a page that shows all results for that Department.

However, in the View configuration (Content Pane variant) I enable the More link to show, but it doesn't show.

Any ideas why the More link wouldn't show? I've definitely got enough content and I've even tried setting the configuration so that it'll show the More link even if there isn't more data.

Are More links disabled when displaying the view in a content pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this module to define more link for each pane

[Views Panes More Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_panes_more_link)

> Adding the ability to define a custom "More Link" link for View Panes.
>
> Just go to the view pane settings and you will find a new fieldset
>   which will allow you to define the new custom "More Link".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I solved it by creating a page view as well as an original block view.

Hope this helps